# Django обращается к несуществующему полю в базе данных

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

уважаемые знатоки питона и django

При обращении к главной странице сайта, django обращается к несуществующему полю в базе данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом поле description_ru_spb отсутствует в базе, скачанной на проде, отсутствует в классе CarModel - модели для таблицы vans_carmodel, но присутствует в файлах миграции.

Мой вопрос вот в чем: как исправить эту ошибку, и как так получается, что на проде, при том же самом коде и базе этого нет.

Comment: Вы для начала хотя бы посмотрите, какой именно код пытается обратиться к этому полю

Comment: К этому полю обращается view-функция, если конкретно, то
    
    CarExample.objects.all().order_by('?')[:16]

Comment: В комментарии CarExample, а в вопросе CarModel — как так?

Comment: Вот сейчас и разбираюсь, почему так. Я добавил в вопрос скришнот из страницы с ошибкой, в котором описано, в каком месте происходит ошибка

Comment: Скорее всего, ошибка происходит не здесь, а в шаблоне home.html, в котором где-то кто-то использует несуществующее поле

Comment: Я прочесал весь код на наличие этого поля - и оно есть только в файлах миграции. Оба раза оно добавляется в модель.
Заранее извиняюсь, если не знаю каких-то тонкостей. Это мой первый опыт взаимодействия с коммерческим проектом на Django

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно более детально дебажить, так, конечно, ничего не понятно, но если этого поля нет в БД, то, наверное, его стоило бы создать. Самый простой способ - это установить [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```bsh
pip install django-extensions
```

и воспользоваться командой [sqldiff](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqldiff.html)

```bsh
# для всех приложений
./manage.py sqldiff -a 

# для конкретного приложения
./manage.py sqldiff <app_name>
```

Вам будет сгенерирован sql код, который надо выполнить, чтобы структура БД была актуальной (как сделаны модели)

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ.

Comment: Я поставил django-extensions через pip в виртуальное окружение, но manage.py  sqldiff -a завершается ошибкой. Причина
    Unknown command: 'sqldiff'

Comment: Версия - Python2.7

Comment: @VladimirKurbatov https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html

Comment: @VladimirKurbatov, думаю то что у вас появляется ошибка  Unknown command: 'sqldiff', не относится к теме этого вопроса и прежде чем писать сюда, наверное, стоит самому попробовать разобраться в проблеме и уделить ей некоторое время, у меня этот пакет работает корректно и тут проблема исключительно в том что вы сделали что-то неправильно

Comment: К сожалению ответ не помог. Команда приводит к ошибке AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'indexes'
Решил другим способом

Answer (score 0):

Проблем было как минимум две:

1. У двух файлов миграции совпадали dependencies, из-за чего выполнялось изменение ещё не существующего поля
2. Разработчик в какой-то момент просто забил пользоваться моделями и миграциями, и начал делать всё через sql

Чем это вылечил:

1. Более позднему файлу прописал более ранний в dependencies
2. Сделал миграцию
3. Очистил все таблицы при помощи truncate
4. Ещё раз накатил скрипт базы данных, по ходу дела добавляя отсутствующие поля и таблицы вручную